# Sorting by the first Uppercase letter doesn't seem to work

Tags: sort

I need to sort a list like this one, by the first uppercase letter:

```
{alan turing Smith's Prize 1936}
{werner heisenberg Matteucci Medal 1929}
{albert einstein Barnard Medal 1920}
```

From the manual entry for `:sort`, I'd expect that any of those commands would accomplish that:

```
:sort /[^A-Z]*/ 
:sort /[A-Z]/ r
:sort /.\{-}\ze[A-Z]/
```

Instead, sorting is done on the first lowercase:

```
{alan turing Smith's Prize 1936}
{albert einstein Barnard Medal 1920}
{werner heisenberg Matteucci Medal 1929}
```

---

I noticed that if I capitalize the first word, then it sorts that first. As if the pattern only tried to match on the first word, instead of the whole line:

```
{Werner heisenberg Matteucci Medal 1929}
{alan turing Smith's Prize 1936}
{albert einstein Barnard Medal 1920}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Looks like you have [`'ignorecase'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ignorecase%27) enabled... You can check it with `:set ic?`. Without it being on, the first one you used (`:sort /[^A-Z]*/`) worked for me.

Comment: @filbranden thats correct, I had `ignorecase` enabled. When I did `set noignorecase` and tried again, it worked.

Comment: I was going to suggest setting [`'smartcase'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smartcase%27) together with `'ignorecase'` (that's what I typically use), but I found that `:sort` doesn't seem to respect it... Filed a bug about it: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7322

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort pattern is *skipped*, so you could use

```
sort /.\{-}\ze\u/
```

or

```
sort r /\u\+/
```

(the `r` should cause it sort on the matching parts.)

Importantly, any lines not matching are kept in order, but separated.

---

I recognize these are similar to what you tried (with `\u` instead of `[A-Z]`). For some reason, it actually made a difference for me. That is, using `[A-Z]` didn't work in either command, but `\u` did. Odd.

Answer (score 3):

Commands such as `:sort /[^A-Z]*/` to skip non-uppercase letters should typically work, except when [`'ignorecase'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ignorecase%27) is set, which makes that pattern case-insensitive and will skip characters other than *any* letters, be them uppercase or lowercase. From the comments, it looks like you do have `'ignorecase'` enabled.

You *might* have the pattern `/[^A-Z]*/` work correctly in a search to match non-uppercase letters (including lowercase ones), if in addition to `'ignorecase'` you also have [`'smartcase'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smartcase%27) enabled. Having both `'ignorecase'` and `'smartcase'` both enabled is a pretty common setup, since it's quite an useful combination. Make searches case-insensitive if you have all lowercase characters, but case-sensitive if you have any uppercase characters anywhere.

But it turns out that **the `:sort` command recognizes the `'ignorecase'` setting, but not the `'smartcase'` setting!** That's why you might see one behavior for patterns in search, but a subtly different one in sorts.

I opened [an issue on the Vim issue tracker about this](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7322) and the conclusion is that this is the intended behavior (or, if not initially defined this way on purpose, will be maintained as such to prevent breaking backwards compatibility.) A recent update to Vim runtimes [included an update to the documentation to call this out explicitly](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/4466ad6baa22485abb1147aca3340cced4778a66#diff-6a5ba7723775463d3efe8549c14e5d64425287328acfe1dbc0539c47a7286df1), initially shipped with Vim version 8.2.2026. The updated documentation simply states that "`'ignorecase'` applies to the pattern, but `'smartcase'` is not used."

In your case, you can use [the suggestions from D. Ben Knoble's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28060/18609), such as `:sort /.\{-}\ze\u/` or `:sort r /\u\+/`.

Another option is to use an explicit [`\C`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CC) in your pattern, to force it to be case-insensitive, regardless of the `'ignorecase'` setting:

```
:sort /\C[^A-Z]*/
```